# How to set the AFM configuration in this doped monolayer system?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, magnetism

The figure below illustrates a 2x2x1 supercell of transition metal-doped CrI$_3$ monolayer. The red, green, and black atoms represent Cr, I, and transition metal atoms, respectively. I want to calculate the energy of this doped monolayer in the AFM configuration, but I don't know how to set it. Please I need your urgent help on how to set the spins of the atoms for the AFM configuration for this doped monolayer. I mean which ones to set up, and which ones to set down? should I increase the supercell size?

[image: set]

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I would expect the AFM configuration to be such that neighbouring Cr/TM atoms have opposite spins, with a very small total net spin -- zero for a perfect AFM, but the presence of a TM other than Cr will probably change that. Is that what you meant?

Comment: All I can find online is that the layers are *ferromagnetic*, with antiferromagnetic coupling between the layers. Is that what you meant?

Comment: You can technically do this in ASE pretty easily.  How do you currently run calculations? Manually construct INCAR?

Comment: @TristanMaxson I think the question is more about which atoms are "up" and which are "down"

Comment: @PhilHasnip I think either way it needs clarification, presumably to set AFM you would just set it to the same as the undoped cell.  AFM stacking between layers seems more likely than AFM intralayer, but in the doped cell I think this must end up as Ferrimagnetic since the transition metal is unlikely to take the exact same magnetic moment as the Cr (or even flip spin and be far from AFM).

Comment: @TristanMaxson I agree completely, it's very unlikely to be a perfect AFM if it's planar, with a non-Cr atom in there. I do think interlayer AFM is more likely though, and if this is really just a monolayer in this case, then there's nothing to simulate.

Comment: There's been 6 comments here. Were they useful? Have you figured out the answer to this problem? Please update us!

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP responds to questions/suggestions in the comments.